# Does the amount of people you kill and/or knock out change the ending in Bioshock Infinite's Burial at Sea part 2?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Without getting in to some spoiler-ish details, very early on in this DLC you are faced with the situation to knock out a person in your path. After doing so, and I'm going to have to paraphrase from here, you state that "it's only going to get messier from here", and are told that "just how messy it gets is up to you".

This, to me, seems to imply that the ending of this DLC changes based on how many kills you make, possibly how many knock-outs too. Does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burial at Sea is a linear story, unfortunately. While stealthily taking down opponents is useful for the '98 mode achievement, it has no impact on the ending.

Part 2 has just one ending, though it would be great to have seen some different resolutions.